# Open Layer interference between two interaction.select events

Tags: select, cluster-computing, openlayers

I have a problem with cluster interactions: on click on the cluster the map should zoom in to the cluster unless that the cluster contains 2 objects with the same latitude and longitude.
In this last case, it should spread the cluster with an animation.

The 2 interactions, separately, are working perfectly, my problems start when I have to mix them, so to obtain the behaviour mentioned before.

My last result is that on clicking on the cluster the map doesn't zoom in to it if the cluster contains objects with the same latitude and longitude BUT it is not spread the cluster.
If, instead, I comment the code line concern the zoom (//this.map.addInteraction(clusterClick);), the cluster spreading works.

This is my code:

```
        // Select interaction to spread cluster out and select features
        this.selectCluster = new ol.interaction.SelectCluster({
          // Point radius: distance between the features
          pointRadius:37,
          animate: true,
          style: this.selectedClusterStyle,
        });
        this.map.addInteraction(this.selectCluster);

         var clusterClick = new ol.interaction.Select({
              layer: this.clusterLayer,
              style: this.selectedClusterStyle
          });

         clusterClick.on('select',function(event) {
           var eventFeature = event.selected[0];
           var features = eventFeature.get('features');
           if (features.length>1){

               var extent = ol.extent.createEmpty();
               var i = 1;
               var twoExtentWithSameCoordinate = false;

               lat = parseInt(features[0].getGeometry().flatCoordinates[0],10);
               long = parseInt(features[0].getGeometry().flatCoordinates[1],10);
               ol.extent.extend(extent, features[0].getGeometry().getExtent());

               while(i<=features.length){
                    if(features[i]){
                        ol.extent.extend(extent, features[i].getGeometry().getExtent());
                        if((parseInt(features[i].getGeometry().flatCoordinates[0],10) == lat) && (parseInt(features[i].getGeometry().flatCoordinates[1],10) == long)){
                                twoExtentWithSameCoordinate = true;
                        }

                    }
                    i++
               }
               if(twoExtentWithSameCoordinate == false){
                    this.getMap().getView().fit(extent, {padding: [150, 150, 150, 150]});
               }else{
                    //it should spread the cluster
                    clusterClick.getFeatures().clear();
                    this.selectCluster.getFeatures().push(features);
               }
           }else{
                clusterClick.getFeatures().clear()
                var record = eventFeature.values_.features[0].values_.record;
                var dialog = Ext.create('Traccar.view.dialog.Beacon');
                dialog.objectStore = Ext.getStore('Beacons');
                dialog.down('form').loadRecord(record);
                dialog.show();
           }
         });
         this.map.addInteraction(clusterClick);
```

to me seems that the 2 select interactions interfere with each other compromising the behaviour.
But I can't figure out how to handle it

Comment: See https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/issues/9945  The `ol.interaction.Select` could probably be replaced by `map.forEachFeatureAtPixel`

Comment: I don't understand how it can help. In the link discussion, the user wanted that each layer has its own select interaction.
In my case, I have only one layer, the cluster layer, with two different iterations, at the moment separated, that should be combined in somehow so to obtain the behaviour mentioned in the description.
In my code, I already tried to combine them but seems to not work, or anyway seems that one excludes the other.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution:

```
 var clusterClick = new ol.interaction.SelectCluster({
              layer: this.clusterLayer,
              style: this.selectedClusterStyle,
              pointRadius:37,
        });

        clusterClick.on('select',function(event) {
           var eventFeature = event.selected[0];

           if(eventFeature != null){
               var features = eventFeature.get('features');
               if (features.length>1){
                   var extent = ol.extent.createEmpty();
                   var i = 1;
                   var twoExtentWithSameCoordinate = false;
                   lat = parseInt(features[0].getGeometry().flatCoordinates[0],10);
                   long = parseInt(features[0].getGeometry().flatCoordinates[1],10);
                   ol.extent.extend(extent, features[0].getGeometry().getExtent());
                   while(i<=features.length){
                        if(features[i]){
                            ol.extent.extend(extent, features[i].getGeometry().getExtent());
                            if((parseInt(features[i].getGeometry().flatCoordinates[0],10) == lat) && (parseInt(features[i].getGeometry().flatCoordinates[1],10) == long)){
                                    twoExtentWithSameCoordinate = true;
                            }
                        }
                        i++
                   }
                   if(twoExtentWithSameCoordinate == false){
                        clusterClick.getFeatures().clear();
                        this.getMap().getView().fit(extent, {padding: [150, 150, 150, 150]});
                   }
               }else{
                    clusterClick.getFeatures().clear()
                    var record = eventFeature.values_.features[0].values_.record;
                    var dialog = Ext.create('Traccar.view.dialog.Beacon');
                    dialog.objectStore = Ext.getStore('Beacons');
                    dialog.down('form').loadRecord(record);
                    dialog.show();
               }
           }
        });
        this.map.addInteraction(clusterClick);
```

Maybe it can be useful for someone else :D